# Get total value of the same column multiple rows and total of two different rows (mysql query)

Tags: mysql

I have a table "records"
[Records][1]

```
select typeofservice, 
       Coalesce(sum(incomecost,expensecost),0) 'incomecost,expensecost' 
from   records 
where  dateoftrans = '2016-11-22' 
group by typeofservice with rollup;
```

I want to be able to have the result on the second image and this is my query... and all of this transactions happened on one day. Please help

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLYav.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only for second image's result, you can try `sum(incomecost)` and `sum(expensecost)` like this:

```
SELECT
    typeofservice,
    Coalesce(SUM(incomecost), 0) AS incomecost,
    Coalesce(SUM(expensecost), 0) AS expensecost
FROM records
GROUP BY typeofservice
WITH ROLLUP
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query assumes that, for a given type of service, you want to report an income when the sum of the income cost exceeds the sum of the expense cost, and vice-versa.  In each case, the difference between income and expense is reported in the appropriate column, with `NULL` being reported in the alternate column.

```
SELECT typeofservice,
       CASE WHEN SUM(incomecost) - SUM(expensecost) > 0
            THEN SUM(incomecost) - SUM(expensecost)
            ELSE NULL END AS incomecost,
       CASE WHEN SUM(expensecost) - SUM(incomecost) > 0
            THEN SUM(expensecost) - SUM(incomecost)
            ELSE NULL END AS expensecost
FROM records
WHERE dateoftrans = '2016-11-22'
GROUP BY typeofservice
WITH ROLLUP
```